# python - unbound method must be called with instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a log in form which let's the user go to the sign up form if he/she doesn't have an account yet. Here is my code.

from Tkinter import *

```
class myLogin():
def __init__(self):
    self.form = Tk()
    self.form.title("Log in")
    self.form.option_add("*font",("Arial",12,"normal"))
    self.form.geometry("500x400+430+200")
    self.frm = Frame(self.form, width = 700, height = 500)
    self.lab1 = Label(self.frm, text="Username:")
    self.lab1.grid(row=0,sticky=W)
    self.entr1 = Entry(self.frm, width = 15)
    self.entr1.focus_set()
    self.entr1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

    self.lab2 = Label(self.frm, text="Password:")
    self.lab2.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

    self.entr2 = Entry(self.frm, width=15, show='*')
    self.entr2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

    checkbox = Checkbutton(self.frm, text="Keep me logged in")
    checkbox.grid(column=1,columnspan=2)

    self.btn2 = Button(self.frm, text = "Log-in", command = self.login, width=10)
    self.btn2.grid(row=3, sticky = E, columnspan = 2)

    self.lab3 = Label(self.frm, text="Don't have an account?")
    self.lab3.grid(row=4,column=1)
    self.btn3 = Button(self.frm, text = "Register", command = mySignUp.register, width=10)
    self.btn3.grid(row=5, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

    self.frm.pack()
    self.form.mainloop()



def login(self):
    user=[]
    pw=[]
    ctr=0

    with open('users.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                if(ctr%2==0):
                    user.append(word)
                else:
                    pw.append(word)
                ctr+=1

    userctr=0;
    for eachuser in user:
        if((user[userctr] == self.entr1.get()) and (pw[userctr]== self.entr2.get())):
            print("ok")
            userctr+=1

class mySignUp(myLogin):
def register(self):
    #self.destroy()
    root = Tk()
    top = Toplevel(root)

    top.title("Register")
    top.geometry("500x400+430+200")

    top.transient(root)
    top.lab1 = Label(top, text="Username:")
    top.lab1.grid(row=0,sticky=W)
    top.inpusername = Entry(top, width = 15)
    top.inpusername.focus_set()
    top.inpusername.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

    top.lab2 = Label(top, text="Password:")
    top.lab2.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

    top.inppw = Entry(top, width=15, show='*')
    top.inppw.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

    top.btn2 = Button(top, text = "Sign up", command = self.addUser, width=10)
    top.btn2.grid(row=3, sticky = E, columnspan = 2)

    #top.lab1.pack()
    #top.form.mainloop()
    root.mainloop()

def addUser(self):
    ob = register()
    import cgi
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    print 
    username = ob.top.inpusername.get()
    password = ob.top.inppw.get()
    print(username)
    print(password)
    #print "The user entered %s" % form.getvalue("entr1")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = myLogin()
    #login()
    #window = Window(None)

    #window.title("title")

    #window.mainloop()
```

When the user click the register button, it should call the register method at class mySignUp() and the sign up form should pop up
But I am getting this error

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: unbound method register() must be called with mySignUp instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You must call the bound method `register` with an instance of the class `mySignUp`, i.e. the first line of `addUser` should read

```
ob = self.register()
```

because python won't know which `mySignUp` you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You call it like a class method, use:

```
mysignup= mySignUp()
self.btn3 = Button(self.frm, text = "Register", command = mysignup.register, width=10)
```